# Dynamically generated svg isn't rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, svg

Hey I am having trouble with a simple svg clipPath...

I have a simple img inside a div

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="xxxxxxx" class="clipped">
</div>
```

with a svg clipPath where I have javascript that automatically generates the widths of the rect's...

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0" y="0.1" width="0" height="0.85" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

with multiple rect elements defined.  If I hard code the  elements into the html (example of 5 elemetns) everything works fine but I wrote a function to choose the amount of rects and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

It generates the rects with the correct attributes (x, y, width, height) and inserts them into the DOM.  When I open the inspector I can see them in the DOM but it is showing width and height as auto so nothing is showing up even though I have the width and height attr set.  Here is the javascript snippet.

```
function createRects(num) {
    let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let temp = document.createElement("rect"),
        yVal = rnd(0, 0.18);
    temp.setAttribute("x", 0);
    temp.setAttribute("y", yVal);
    temp.setAttribute("width", 0);
    temp.setAttribute("height", (rnd(0.80, 1) - yVal));
    frag.appendChild(temp);
  };
  return frag;
}
const clipPathNode = document.querySelector("#clipPath");
var fragment = createRects(8);
clipPathNode.appendChild(fragment);
```

So everything works correctly when hardcoding the number of rects for the clipPath but when trying to dynamically generate them something is going wrong even though they are being put into the DOM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a link to the codepen.
https://codepen.io/eth0s/pen/ejdyLJ

Comment: Not sure how this would be a duplicate of that question.  I know how to create an SVG tag with javascript, as you can see from my question if you read it.  I created the svg element just fine and can see it in the DOM; that wasn't my question.

Comment: `document.createElement("rect")` is meant to be an SVG element

Comment: The issue is not (only) the way new svg elements are created and adorned but in particular the way in which they are added to the dom, taking the detour of a `documentFragment`. Thus voted to reopen. (Check with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBmvVv))

Comment: @collapsar Yeah changing from `createElement` to `createElementNS` fixed it, thanks!  Could you elaborate a little bit why just adding a namespace URI fixes it and what you meant by how they are added to the dom with `documentFragment`?  In other words is the only reason I needed to use the namespace because I am using `documentFragment`?

Comment: @AndrewBone I know what `document.createElement("rect")` is meant to be used for.  An svg element is exactly what I was trying to create.  Can you explain why you marked this question as a duplicate?

Comment: because you can't create SVG rect elements with createElement as the answer in the duplicate explains.

Comment: @TravisJames html and svg are vocabularies with different semantics and potentially conflicting lexical items. Namespaces tell them apart. Which is a good thing because different semantics mean for example different APIs. Creating a node in the generic DOM API without namespace info would mean that the element's API would not be deferred until this info became available / could be 'guessed', eg. after insertion in the DOM - perhaps feasible for inline svg but not a clean design, also complicating things for svg's `foreignObject` ...

Comment: @TravisJames ... As for the use of `documentFragment`in your code, in principle, you don't need it: collect the newly created DOM nodes in an array and insert it into the DOM tree in a single sweep. I have not checked performance issues, though. It is not related to the actual problem anyway,

Comment: @collapsar awesome thank you for the info it has help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird thing I discovered at one point, but I think you need to use `createElementNS` for creating svg elements. Try using this in place of `document.createElement('rect')` and see if it has the desired effect.

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "rect")
```

Comment: Awesome that solved it!  So basically the only difference is needed a namespace URI for svg elements...

Thanks a lot!